# Akka stream to actor issue

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to stream an http response to an actor using Sink.actorRefWithAck but somehow nothing is sent to this sink actor but the init and complete msgs. I am probably missing something really obvious though.
The sink actor is well being initiated. Here is the code for the streaming actor:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
    case GetTestData(p, id) =>
      // Get the data and pipes it to itself through a message as recommended
  
      http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = uri.format(p, id)))
        .pipeTo(self)

    case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, _, entity, _) =>
      // Sink as actorRef
      val sink = Sink.actorRefWithAck(context.actorOf(TestJob2.props(), "testJob2Actor"), Init, Ack, Complete)
      // Pipe the response body to the actor sink
      entity.dataBytes.runWith(sink)

    case resp @ HttpResponse(code, _, _, _) =>
      log.error("Request to test job failed, response code: " + code)
      // Discard the flow to avoid backpressure
      resp.discardEntityBytes()

    case _ => log.warning("Unexpected message in TestJobActor")
}
```

and here the code for the sink actor:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case Init =>
    log.info("TestJob2Actor got init sink message")
    sender ! Ack

  case Complete => log.info("TestJob2Actor got complete sink message")

  case b: ByteString =>
    log.debug(b.utf8String)
    sender ! Ack

  case _ => log.warning("Unexpected message in TestJob2Actor")
}
```

output:

> 2018-01-25 17:26:58,530 INFO  com.mcma.actors.Supervisor akka.tcp://alor-system@10.33.135.82:8000/user/supervisorActor - SupervisorActor forwarded GetTestData message to TestJobActor
>
> 2018-01-25 17:26:59,243 INFO  com.mcma.actors.jobs.TestJob akka.tcp://alor-system@10.33.135.82:8000/user/supervisorActor/testJobActor - TestJob actor started
>
> 2018-01-25 17:27:00,052 INFO  com.mcma.actors.jobs.TestJob2 akka.tcp://alor-system@10.33.135.82:8000/user/supervisorActor/testJobActor/testJob2Actor - TestJob2 actor started
>
> 2018-01-25 17:27:00,067 INFO  com.mcma.actors.jobs.TestJob2 akka.tcp://alor-system@10.33.135.82:8000/user/supervisorActor/testJobActor/testJob2Actor - TestJob2Actor got init sink message
>
> 2018-01-25 17:27:00,083 INFO  com.mcma.actors.jobs.TestJob2 akka.tcp://alor-system@10.33.135.82:8000/user/supervisorActor/testJobActor/testJob2Actor - TestJob2Actor got complete sink message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideas: (1) the `Source` from `entity.dataBytes` could be empty, or (2) the sink actor is actually processing the `ByteString` chunks, but the logging level is such that debug messages are not visible. Try setting your logging level to DEBUG, or change `log.debug(b.utf8String)` to `log.info(b.utf8String)`.

Comment: Question though, I just have one single log line with the whole json message at once, which is quite small but I don't get why it is not logged by bytes if I have a byte stream?

Comment: To chunk up the `Source` as valid JSON `ByteString` segments, you could use [`JsonFraming`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.9/akka/stream/scaladsl/JsonFraming$.html): `entity.dataBytes.via(JsonFraming.objectScanner(Int.MaxValue)).runWith(sink)`

Comment: thanks, it is properly chunking json objects and sending messages one by one to the actor.
That said, the goal of the system being just to act as a pipe: receiving a big http response and streaming back the data stream via http in the sink actor, what would be the best approach performance wise? Because I think that atm the stream concept would be broken if I make an http request on each message/json obj received right? Is there a possibility to maintain the http connection using header “Transfer-Encoding: chunked” header for ex.?